# How to pass two properties in ngModel in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8, angular9

Hi i am working on Angular 7 project. I want to send id to API request and text in if conditions.

Here is the example:

```
[{id: 2, text: 'upper'},{id: 3, text: 'Lower'} ]
```

Here i want to use text in my if conditions and also i am pushing all this values to a object in my class

Here is my HTML :

```
   <select class="form-control" name="objtype" [(ngModel)]="obj.text" (change)="changedropdown()" required>
```

Here to the request i am able to send only text because i am using `[(ngModel)]="obj.text"`  now i want to send id to the request without `ngModel`. Any solution for this? TIA.

Comment: It should be as simple as changing the value of `[(ngModel)]` to `obj.id`. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: I know it but what i am asking is without changing the ngModel which i mentioned already i want to send only id to the API request.

Comment: @Yakub, your question does not say _only_ the `id`. Don't add revisions in a comment and not in the question. In fact your question is titled "how to pass two properties."

Answer (score 0):

The trick to this is to use to bind an object to both the `<select>`'s `ngModel` and each `<option>`'s `ngValue`, customizing comparison for `id` based equality via `compareWith`.

**component.html**

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selected" [compareWith]="compareById">
  <option *ngFor="let option of options" [ngValue]="option">
     {{option.text}}
  </option>
</select>
```

**component.ts**

```
options = [
  {id: 2, text: 'upper'},
  {id: 3, text: 'Lower'}
];

selected: {id: number, text: string} | undefined;

compareById = <T extends {id: number}>(x: T, y: T) => x.id === y.id;
```